# What is the best Linear Algebra videos to go with Ron Larson Elementary Linear Algebra Book?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, education, online-resources

My course teacher teaches out from the Ron Larson Elementary Linear Algebra Book teaching proofs and theorems which I find hard to grasp as we cover over a chapter in two hours. So I looking for Linear Algebra videos which teach concepts maybe with proofs and theorems involved.

Comment: Have you looked into Kahn Academy?

Comment: Yes it is not in depth enough